# Root resource from other .jar file cannot be looked up in JAX-RS application

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jax-rs, jndi

I am trying to build an application ear file with the following structure:

```
app.ear
--> lib
    -- app-domain.jar
    -- app-api.jar
    -- app-common.jar
    ...
--> META-INF
    -- application.xml
    -- glassfish-application.xml
    -- MANIFEST.MF
-- app-ejb.jar
-- app-rs.war
```

The app-api.jar file contains my remote interfaces like

```
@Remote
public interface LanguageService {

    /**
     * @return all languages known to the system
     */
    List<Language> loadLanguages();
```

The implementation is contained in the app-ejb.jar file and looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(LanguageService.class)
@Path("/language")
public class LanguageServiceImpl extends ValidatingService implements LanguageService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "kcalculator")
    EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Override
    public List<Language> loadLanguages() {
        CriteriaQuery<Language> query = createLoadLanguageQuery();
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();                
    }
```

And finally I want to provide this as an JAX-RS web service and thus have my implementation of the javax.rs.Application class in the app-rs.war file, which looks like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(LanguageServiceImpl.class);
        return s;
    }
```

This deploys without any problem, the application class is also detected. However, when i finally access the web service an internal server error occurs due to a NPE.

The LanguageServiceImpl cannot be looked up, the log contains the following entry:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:module/LanguageServiceImpl!com.kcalculator.ejb.LanguageServiceImpl
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 63 more
```

Hence the file is considered a Pojo, and so the reference to the entity manager is not initialized, which finally results in the Nullpointer exception.

I am kinda stuck, as annotating the bean class and giving it a mapped name is not working. Putting my application class into the ejb.jar file does not solve the problem either.

Can anyone point out what i am missing here?

Additional comment:
What I found out in the meantime: If I add a stateless session bean to my app-rs.war file and register it in MyApplication, it works without any problem. There injecting the LanguageService works, too. So it seems the problem is related to the fact that the service implementing bean class is located in another artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in one of the previous comments, a working solution was found by moving the session beans to the web archive as well. Thus the separation between the ejb .jar file and the disclosing web service containing project is gone, however it seems rational to have the services in the artifact that is also supposed to provide the web services.

Thanks for the hints, however it is still not clear to me (according to the specification) why the initially described approach should not be feasible (but i realized it isn't...).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you have an EJB with a remote interface. 
JAX-RS 1.1 states in 6.2 that JAX-RS annotations only need to be supported on no-interface beans and local interfaces:

> JAX-RS annotations MAY be applied to a bean’s local interface or directly to a no-interface bean.

Comment: I removed the @Remote annotation from the service bean, but still the same exception occurs.

Comment: Could you please try adding @LocalBean to the EJB?

Comment: I just tried that, but it has no effect. The problem remains.

Comment: Then I think that the lookup is done in the context of the web module. You probably have to move your EJB to the war to make java:module/... work.

Comment: Yes, that might be the final solution. I am just wondering if the scenario I described is really that artificial and that the standard does not consider it. I will continue to look for a solution for a day or two, and give an update here on my findings.

Comment: I think it is unusual in so far as resources usually are in the same web module and that if the resource requires access to some central EJB in the ear it contains a "wrapper" resource that accesses this EJB.